# Test whether a string representing an object n-levels deep is available

Tags: javascript

I was writing some JavaScript that depended on several global variables being present.

I read about the "guard pattern" from a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954664/2295034) but since I need to check for multiple objects it quickly becomes quite tedious to have lines like this everywhere:

```
if (foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz) {
    // access foo.bar.baz
}
```

I wanted to replace the above with:

```
if (isAvailable("foo.bar.baz")) {
    // access foo.bar.baz
}
```

Here is the implementation for `isAvailable`:

```
// test whether a string that represents an object in a certain
// context (using dot notation) of n-levels deep is available
function isAvailable(s,context) {
    var aSplit, ob;

    if (s === undefined || s === null) {
        return false;
    }

    aSplit = s.split('.');
    ob = context[aSplit.shift()];
    while (ob !== undefined && aSplit.length > 0) {
        ob = ob[aSplit.shift()];
    }
    return typeof ob === "object";
}
```

Here is a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/jokowomepo/edit?js,console

Also, I should mention that I am only interested in solving this problem with vanilla JavaScript...no libs.

My implementation seems to work, but I'd be interested if there are improvements that could be made.

Any feedback?

Comment: In your test cases in your jsbin you should probably have a test for something like `foo.car = null;` too.

Comment: Fails if value is 0, string, etc. — I would rather check with hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe a matter of taste, but I'm not a big fan of slicing arrays.
I find this alternative implementation using a `for` loop and without array slicing a bit simpler:

```
function isAvailable(s,context) {
    var aSplit, ob, i;

    if (s === undefined || s === null) {
        return false;
    }

    aSplit = s.split('.');
    ob = context;
    for (i = 0; ob !== undefined && i < aSplit.length; ++i) {
        ob = ob[aSplit[i]];
    }
    return typeof ob === "object";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look a bit simpler. But, with JavaScript's hoisting, do you not buy into the "best practice" (per Crockford) that you should have every "var" as the first line of the function since that is where it will be effectively put by the interpreter?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that best practice. Thanks for pointing it out. It makes sense, and I like to follow the recommended practices, so I dropped that point.

Comment: also note that in some situations, for the last line of the function, I had to check for "function" as well as "object" if the passed-in "s" was a function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion

```
function isAvailable(s,context) {
    var aSplit, ob;

    if (s === undefined || s === null || !context) {
        return false;
    }

    aSplit = s.split('.');

    ob = context[aSplit.shift()];

    return !!ob && ((aSplit.length === 0) || isAvailable(aSplit.join("."), ob))

}
```

If ES6 is an option you could have

```
var [head, ...tail] = s.split('.');

ob = context[head];

return !!ob && ((tail.length === 0) || isAvailable(tail.join("."), ob));
```